# Retrieve Specific values by Query for ArrayList or String

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a data-set. The subset for the data;

```
1 clueweb09-en0003-55-31884 0
1 clueweb09-en0006-21-20387 0
1 clueweb09-enwp01-75-20596 1
1 clueweb09-enwp00-64-03709 1
1 clueweb09-en0005-76-03988 0
2 clueweb09-en0011-28-14585 0
2 clueweb09-en0011-89-08538 1
2 clueweb09-en0004-65-01093 0
2 clueweb09-en0001-41-26637 0
2 clueweb09-enwp00-29-10792 0
2 clueweb09-enwp03-38-18865 0
```

They are all string values. I just want to work, for instance, the first column = 1. After does it have the value 'clueweb09-en0006-21-20387' in the column 2?

I can not compare them like the first char == '1' because the dataset has 10, 11 even 100.

I am using String[] for each row and ArrayList for these 3 columns.

Is there a practical way to retrieve those specific values? Or what is the best way to do that operation?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have each row in a string array right? So, use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to split whichever row you want to work with

Comment: If all the rows look like '1 clueweb09-en0003-55-31884 0' and are strings why not split on space ' ' and take the second element. Alternatively if the width of the columns is consistent across all rows you could use a substring based on start and end positions.

Comment: Thanks both of you, however, I know how to split and take the column. My problem is, is there anything like 'WHERE firstcolumn = 1 AND secondcolumn = 'clueweb09-en0006-21-20387'?

Answer (score 2):

you can iterate over each string from the array,
for each string, split it based on " " and accordingly use that column using the resulting index.. eg:

```
    String a = "11 clueweb09-en0003-55-31884 0";
    String[] a1=a.split(" ");
    System.out.println(a1[1]);//to extract 2nd column
     System.out.println(a1[0]);// to extract 1st column
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but that was not my question. Indeed I know how to split and take the column. The problem is, could I retrieve the row like 'WHERE firstcolumn = 1 AND secondcolumn = 'clueweb09-en0006-21-20387'?